# Laravel validation exists in this table OR that table

Tags: laravel

I need to validate the existence of an API request parameter
but check it in one of two tables, users and teachers
something like this

```
$rules = ['apiToken' => 'required|string|min:70|exists:users,api_token ((OR)) exists:teachers,api_token']
```

is there a way to achieve this using Laravel validator?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: You probably need to create a custom rule for that: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#using-rule-objects

Comment: @Ross Wilson 5.8

Comment: @RossWilson thanks for the answer, I appreciate your effort and the time spent. The thing is that I was searching for a simple built-in validation, so I didn't try your solution as it is custom. When I am looking for a quick solution I skip solutions that require trying something new. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

For something like this you will probably need to use [custom validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#using-closures):

```php
$rules = [
    'apiToken' => [
        'required', 'string', 'min:70', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {

            if (!DB::table('users')->where('api_token', $value)->exists() || !DB::table('teachers')->where('api_token', $value)->exists()) {
                return $fail("The provided $attribute is not valid.");
            }
        }
    ]
];
```

You can change the returned error message by editing the text passed to the `$fail` function.

Comment: $rules = [
    'apiToken' => [
        'required', 'string', 'min:70', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {

            if (!(DB::table('users')->where('api_token', $value)->exists() || DB::table('teachers')->where('api_token', $value)->exists())) {
                return $fail("The provided $attribute is not valid.");
            }
        }
    ]
];